# Texture2D: Error uploading compressed texture level: 0. glError: 0x0500

Tags: c++, windows, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

i created new project i added:

```
 Size winSize = Director::getInstance()->getWinSize();
  RenderTexture* pRenderTexture  = RenderTexture::create(winSize.width, winSize.height, Texture2D::PixelFormat::BGRA8888);
```

and i keep getting this error:

```
cocos2d: Texture2D: Error uploading compressed texture level: 0 . glError: 0x0500
Assert failed: Could not attach texture to framebuffer
Assertion failed!
```

by the way the cpp-test RenderTexture example do work . 
what im doing wrong here ?

Using:

- cocos2d-x v3.3
- win7 32bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that BGRA8888 is not supported by your opengl. Use RGBA8888 if it suitable for you.
And you have typo:

```
RenderTexture* pRenderTexture; = RenderTexture::create
_____________________________^
```

Comment: its was mistake when coping the code i fixed the original